# Best way to add, deploy and remove the solutions in Sharepoint 2013 Environment?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2013

We have a plugin, on installation of this plugin, we have an "exe" which will add and deploy the solution(.wsp files) in central configuration site. On Un - installation of the plugin, the exe will deactivate the activated features related to our plugin, retract the solution and finally remove the solution. This plugin will be installed in all web front ends.

For performing the above operation, we can use PowerShell commands or SharePoint APIS (as STSADM is deprecated, I am not including that).

May I know the best way to do the same? Below are some of my observations

PowerShell commands:

There are two ways in this also

1. Passing the PowerShell commands to System.Diagnostics.Process

   ```
   ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("<PowerShellExePath>", "<ScriptToExecute or Powershell File Name");

   Process process = new Process();
   process.StartInfo = pInfo;
   process.Start()
   ```
2. Runspace API

   ```
       Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(InitialSessionState.CreateDefault());
       runspace.Open();
       PowerShell powerShellCommand = PowerShell.Create();
       powerShellCommand.Runspace = runspace;
       powerShellCommand.AddScript("Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell");
       powerShellCommand.AddScript(script);

       powerShellCommand.Invoke<string>();
   ```

SharePoint APIs

Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Local.Solutions.Add or Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Local.Solutions.Remove.

Thanks & Regards,

Kalai.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing all that runspace stuff and processstartinfo. What's wrong with `Add-SPSolution` / `Install-SPSolution` Powershell commandlets? Also there are numerous WSP deployment scripts, most famous being the SharePoint SOlution Deployer on codeplex.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comments. I am calling the same powershell commands inside the ProcessStartInfo API. This is to run the commands using the exe.

Comment: Then you got your answer already. Best practice is to use exactly these commands. Check out available PowerShell scripts for complete deployment, but there ain't any magic behind it.

Comment: I want to automate, basically when we run the exe, it should add and deploy the solution to Central administration site. As of now I am using ProcessStart API to run powershell script file, as it takes less time compare to other APIS.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an EXE to run your PowerShell script. Just save the script in a file (e.g. MyScript.ps1) and run it in SharePoint PowerShell console. As suggested in the comments above, you can call SharePoint cmdlets (such as Add-SPSolution) from your script to deploy your WSP and activate the features.

Packaging this logic to EXE increases complexity of the implementation, complicates troubleshooting of the deployment, and therefore should not be considered the best practice.